# how to start activity from google map alert dialog

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I create a map with overlays and i need when i press one of them to show me a dialog with a button and when i press the button to start another activity.How can i do that because i tried with startActivity(intent) but give me error.

public class MiItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {

```
public MiItemizedOverlay(Context context, Drawable defaultMarker) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    this.context = context;
}

public void addLocalizacion(double lat, double lon, String etiqueta) {
    int lt = (int) (lat * 1E6);
    int ln = (int) (lon * 1E6);
    punto = new GeoPoint(lt, ln);
    OverlayItem item = new OverlayItem(punto, etiqueta, null);
    mOverlays.add(item);
    populate();
}

public void clear() {
    mOverlays.clear();
    populate();
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    return mOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return mOverlays.size();
}

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
    dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Go", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, OtraActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    }).create().show();
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Hard to discover your error without logcat!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Context` field of the `MiItemizedOverlay class`

```
@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
    dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Go", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, OtraActivity.class);
            //here
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }).create().show();
    return true;
}
```

also don't forget to dismiss the dialog before calling other Activity

Comment: it`s working, the failure was in my activity (OtraActivity) that cud´t start because of the layout

Answer (score 0):

```
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
    dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Go", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(context, OtraActivity.class);
             dialog.cancel();
             context.startActivity(intent); 
        }});
    dialog.show();
    return true;
}
```